# The values are inconsistent before and after the code of the printed address

Tags: c, gdb, printf, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>                    
#include <stdlib.h>                   
#include <string.h>                   
#include <unistd.h>                   
#include <pthread.h>                  
#include <stdbool.h>                  
                                      
int main()                            
{                                     
    int* p = (int*)malloc(888);       
    printf("%d\n", *(p-2));     // output: 897
    printf("%p\n", (void*)p);         
    printf("%d\n", *(p-2));     // output: 896
    return 0;                         
}
```

i want to get the malloc size from memory block head, but the results have puzzled me.

why the values of `*(p-2)` are inconsistent before and after the code of `printf("%p\n", (void*)p)`?

i also debug it with gdb like this:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.c:10
10          int* p = (int*)malloc(888);
(gdb) p p-2
$1 = (int *) 0xfffffffffffffff8
(gdb) n
11          printf("%d\n", *(p-2));
(gdb) p p-2
$2 = (int *) 0x604b88
(gdb) x /1tw p-2
0x604b88:       00000000000000000000001110000001           // 897
(gdb) n
897
12          printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
(gdb) x /1tw p-2
0x604b88:       00000000000000000000001110000000           // 896
(gdb)
```

I wonder if it has anything to do with the implementation of malloc, When the allocated memory size is 88, everthing is ok, Why is it different when i enter 888?

Comment: Running Environment：gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)

Comment: You are deep into undefined behaviour here. There is no standard implementation of `malloc` and if you do want to obtain the size of a malloc allocated block you would be better off looking for some non-standard function that does this for you. I once worked on a platform where there was a function called `_msize` that got this for you.

Comment: `#include <pthread.h>                  
#include <stdbool.h>` what for? You might want to look at https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L4877

Comment: *"i want to get the malloc size from memory block head"* This isn't the way to do that. If you're stepping that deep into implementation dependence and foregoing any chance of portability, do it right and get the standard library internals for the implementation you're using.Some offer APIs to get this; others just document the layout (sometimes even decently). In this day and age, actual lib source is probably available. So long as you understand there is absolutely nothing portable in this endeavor.